# Use Global Parameters in Power Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a lot of tables where in each of them there is an int filter. I want to simply change that value from editing the parameter here

[image]

and reference it from each query of each table like this

[image]

Is there any way I can do this?

I've tried searching into Power BI docs but I have not found anything yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Either inject the parameter value into the query through string manipulation, like this or use the parameter in a filter in a subsequent step and let "query folding" do its job.  I don't know if query folding works when using SQL against Kusto/ADX, so you may need to use KQL instead.

This query demonstrates both approaches, the `ago` condition is injected into the query text because it can't be folded around the original query, but the filter is added through folding, and will be evaluated by Kusto:

```
let
    KQL = "
SomeTable
| where TIMESTAMP > ago(" & Text.From(WindowDays) & "d)
    ",
    Data = AzureDataExplorer.Contents("yourcluster.kusto.windows.net", "yourdb", KQL, [CaseInsensitive=true]),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Data, each [SomeColumn] = "SomeValue")
    
in
    #"Filtered Rows"
```

And if you don't further filter or select rows the query sent to Kusto will be

```
SomeTable
| where TIMESTAMP > ago(2d)
| where SomeColumn = "SomeValue"
```

But normally your report will add additional filters and select particular columns.

Comment: thanks for the answer! So with a integer parameter called ``param1`` in a query should be like ``ExampleTable | where ago(param1) | summarize count() by ColA, ColB``? If not, how would it be the right format?